# odata many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, odata, webapi

I am developing odata (4.0) service and trying to call linked entities (Controller works with books, I want to get categories). For that I created three models witch describe many-to-many relationship.

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}

public class BookCategory
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Inside startup class I configured relationship between Book and BookCategory.

```
builder.EntitySet<Book>("Book").HasManyBinding(x => x.BookCategories, "BookCategories");
```

Well, now I can get BookCategories entries and if I expand Category from BookCategories I can get category entry. But for me I have an extra link into url - BookCategories.

Do you know how to implement many-to-many without BookCategories, for example url should looks like this: http://ip:port/books(n)/categories

Comment: I have the same problem, workaround is to use \Book?$select=BookCategory which gives me the Ids, but I agree your example is how it should work. Hope somebody answers